# How to create samples using sampling technique from existing arrays?

Tags: julia, sample, sampling

I have two arrays as shown below,

```
x = collect(range(1, 10, length=10))
y = colelct(range(1, 10, length=10))
```

I would like to how can i convert them into either `Sobol` or `Uniform` sample, using their algorithm.

Thanks, look forward to suggestions!

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "Converting arrays into Sobol or Uniform sample"

Comment: For Sobol sampling have a look on the [Sobol.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/Sobol.jl) package.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to sample values (uniformly) from `1:10`? If so, you can just pass the collection to `rand`:

```
julia> rand(1:10, 5)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
  5
  5
  8
  8
```

for the `x` you gave above, that would be

```
julia> x = collect(range(1, 10, length=10)) ;

julia> rand(x, 5)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 4.0
 6.0
 7.0
 3.0
```

I'm not sure about Sobol sampling.